# Question on Lagrange's theorem from homework

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

In one of my homework problems:

In $Z^∗_{13}$ let H = {1, 5, 12, 8}. List the right cosets Ha.
(The elements
of $Z^∗_{n}$
are those i, 1 ≤ i ≤ n − 1 which are relatively prime
to n.
Multiplication is modulo n.)

My question is that doesn't Lagrange's theorem state that the order of all subgroups divide the order of the main group? Doesn't the main group have 13 elements (as 13 is prime) so how could the H group with 4 elements divide that?

Comment: You are confusing $Z_{13}$ with $Z_{13}^\times$. The first has thirteen elements and uses addition, the second has twelve elements (zero is not invertible in $Z_{13}$) and uses multiplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right about Lagrange's theorem. But the group $\mathbb{Z}_{13}^*$ has $12$ elements.

Comment: You're right of course, why is 0 not included by the way?

Comment: $0$ does not have a multiplicative inverse modulo $n$ when $n > 1$. This follows from the fact that $0$ and $n$ are not coprime when $n > 1$ ($n$ divides $0$). Or alternatively: if $0 \cdot x \equiv 1 \mod{n}$ for some $x$, then $0 \equiv 1 \mod {n}$ so $n$ divides $1$.